# pyserial sent byte order wrong

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, pyserial

I am trying to send some data over UART from Raspberry Pi to Arduino. That Arduino relays it over I2C (because of a Raspberry Pi I2C hardware bug). I set it up right. The protocol is simple: first byte is the I2C address, then data follows until we get a byte of value 127, upon that byte, we send the data to I2C. At first it works fine but then it goes totally mental. In this setup I have one I2C Arduino (ID 11) outputting anything that it receives.

Arduino relay code:

```
#include <Wire.h>

#define BUFLEN 34
byte buf[BUFLEN];
int pos = 0;

void setup (void) {
  Serial.begin (115200);
  Wire.begin();
  Serial.println("ready");
}

void sendI2C(int addr, char * data, int len) {
  if (len > 1) {
    Wire.beginTransmission(addr);
    Wire.write(data, len);
    Wire.endTransmission();
  }
}

void loop(void) {
  if (Serial.available()) {
    signed int n = Serial.read();
    if (n >= 0) {
      Serial.print("got: ");
      Serial.println((int) n);
      if (n == 127) {
        sendI2C(buf[0], (char*) &buf+1, pos);
        Serial.print("sending pos: ");
        Serial.println((int) pos);
        pos = 0;
      } else {
        buf[pos] = n;
        pos++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Python Raspberry Pi sender:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import serial
import time
from threading import Thread

port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", baudrate=115200, timeout=3.0)

def to_array(val):
    a = []
    for i in list(str(val)):
        a += [ord(i)]
    return a

class reader(Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            line = port.readline()
            if len(line) > 0:
                print line

r = reader()
r.start()

time.sleep(3)
for i in xrange(0,100):
    a = [11]
    a += to_array("S")
    a += to_array(i)
    a += [127]
    #print "trying to write "+str(a)
    for i in a:
        port.write([i])
        port.flushOutput()
```

I2C output:

```
83 48 0 ####
83 49 0 ####
83 50 0 ####
83 51 0 ####
83 52 0 ####
83 53 0 ####
83 54 0 ####
83 55 0 ####
83 56 0 ####
83 57 0 ####
83 49 48 0 ####
83 49 49 0 ####
83 49 50 0 ####
83 49 51 0 ####
83 49 52 0 ####
83 49 53 0 ####
83 49 54 0 ####
83 49 55 0 ####
83 49 56 0 ####
83 49 57 0 ####
83 50 48 0 ####
83 50 49 0 ####
83 50 50 0 ####
83 50 51 11 83 52 11 11 50 0 ####
83 11 56 11 83 57 51 11 ####
83 51 51 11 ####
51 11 51 83 83 ####
83 11 ####
83 51 52 11 52 53 51 ####
52 51 ####
83 53 54 83 ####
```

Python code output (with the arduino relay output):

```
ready

got: 11

got: 83

got: 48

got: 127

sending pos: 3

got: 11

got: 83

got: 49

got: 127

sending pos: 3

got: 11

got: 83

got: 50

got: 127

sending pos: 3

got: 11

got: 83

got: 51

got: 127

sending pos: 3

got: 11

got: 83

got: 52

got: 127

sending pos: 3

got: 11

got: 83

got: 53

got: 127

sending pos: 3

got: 11

got: 83

got: 54

got: 127

sending pos: 3

got: 11

got: 83

got: 55

got: 127

sending pos: 3

got: 11

got: 83

got: 56

got: 127

sending pos: 3

got: 11

got: 83

got: 57

got: 127

sending pos: 3

got: 11

got: 83

got: 49

got: 48

got: 127

sending pos: 4

got: 11

got: 83

got: 49

got: 49

got: 127

sending pos: 4

got: 11

got: 83

got: 49

got: 50

got: 127

sending pos: 4

got: 11

got: 83

got: 49

got: 51

got: 127

sending pos: 4

got: 11

got: 83

got: 49

got: 52

got: 127

sending pos: 4

got: 11

got: 83

got: 49

got: 53

got: 127

sending pos: 4

got: 11

got: 83

got: 49

got: 54

got: 127

sending pos: 4

got: 11

got: 83

got: 49

got: 55

got: 127

sending pos: 4

got: 11

got: 83

got: 49

got: 56

got: 127

sending pos: 4

got: 11

got: 83

got: 49

got: 57

got: 127

sending pos: 4

got: 11

got: 83

got: 50

got: 48

got: 127

sending pos: 4

got: 11

got: 83

got: 50

got: 49

got: 127

sending pos: 4

got: 11

got: 83

got: 50

got: 50

got: 127

sending pos: 4

got: 11

got: 83

got: 50

got: 51

got: 11

got: 83

got: 52

got: 11

got: 11

got: 50

got: 127

sending pos: 10

got: 11

got: 83

got: 11

got: 56

got: 11

got: 83

got: 57

got: 51

got: 127

sending pos: 8

got: 83

got: 127

sending pos: 1

got: 11

got: 83

got: 51

got: 51

got: 127

sending pos: 4

got: 83

got: 127

sending pos: 1

got: 11

got: 51

got: 11

got: 51

got: 83

got: 127

sending pos: 5

got: 11

got: 83

got: 127

sending pos: 2

got: 127

sending pos: 0

got: 52

got: 11

got: 83

got: 52

got: 52

got: 127

sending pos: 5

got: 11

got: 83

got: 51

got: 52

got: 11

got: 52

got: 53

got: 127

sending pos: 7

got: 11

got: 52

got: 127

sending pos: 2

got: 52

got: 56

got: 52

got: 57

got: 127

sending pos: 4

got: 83

got: 53

got: 53

got: 11

got: 83

got: 53

got: 127

sending pos: 6

got: 53

got: 51

got: 127

sending pos: 2

got: 83

got: 52

got: 127

sending pos: 2

got: 11

got: 83

got: 53

got: 54

got: 127

sending pos: 4

got: 53

got: 55

got: 127

sending pos: 2

got: 11

got: 127

sending pos: 1

got: 48

got: 50

got: 127

sending pos: 2

got: 54

got: 11

got: 83

got: 11

got: 83

got: 127

sending pos: 5

got: 55

got: 55

got: 11

got: 11

got: 53

got: 83

got: 55

got: 127

sending pos: 7

got: 11

got: 127

sending pos: 1

got: 56

got: 127

sending pos: 1

got: 83

got: 83

got: 127

sending pos: 2

got: 11

got: 127

sending pos: 1

got: 127

sending pos: 0

got: 48

got: 83

got: 11

got: 127

sending pos: 3

got: 51

got: 57

got: 83

got: 11

got: 83
```

Comment: Please note that I also tried sending the whole "a" array with write() but it did exactly the same.

Comment: Also, I am aware that if I don't send byte 127 often enough, the arduino will access to an invalid memory address ... that's not what I'm worried about right now.